Unable to "Reshare a post" without commentary in LinkedIn API
I have integrated LinkedIn Reshare API in my app, in accordance with the following official document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2024-07&tabs=http#create-dark-posts:\~:text=ugcPost%3A68447855235931240.-,Reshare%20a%20post,-Note
Here's the sample object the API expects as input:
{
  "author": "urn:li:organization:5515715",
  "commentary": "Sample reshare post",
  "visibility": "PUBLIC",
  "distribution": {
    "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
    "targetEntities": [],
    "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
  },
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false,
  "reshareContext": {
    "parent": "urn:li:share:6957408550713184256"
  }
}

The commentary key in the above request object is mandatory, whereas in the app we have the option to reshare a post instantly without any captions attached.
Is there any workaround or official API for this, to repost without any captions?
PS. I have tried adding commentary = ''  but this still acts as repost with caption on the app (new post is mounted on top of old post)
